# Does MD5 hashing in web-service headers will change encryption in the iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, md5, appstore-approval, commoncrypto

In my app, I have added MD5 hashing in my web-service header, and now I am uploading the app on Appstore, here they ask for does my app changed encryption in new build?

so, do I need to say "yes" or "no" while upload second version of app on Appstore?

Second:
 - If I simply add "ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption" key in my info.plist file with "false" value, do my iOS app approves on AppStore.

Note:
- I have used "CommonCrypto" to generate MD5 hash of the string, not using any third party.

Answer (score 1):

you can say 'No' while uploading the app to the app Store. Also you may use that key in plist. It won't cause rejection.

Hope this helps.